# terraformer-arcgis-parser nodejs module error with sample code?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use the nodejs module: https://github.com/Esri/terraformer-arcgis-parser

The following is my code directly from the sample documentation:

```
var ArcGIS = require('terraformer-arcgis-parser');

// parse ArcGIS JSON, convert it to a Terraformer.Primitive (GeoJSON)
var primitive = ArcGIS.parse({
    x:"-122.6764",
    y:"45.5165",
    spatialReference: {
      wkid: 4326
    }
  });

// take a Terraformer.Primitive or GeoJSON and convert it back to ArcGIS JSON
var point = ArcGIS.convert({
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [45.5165, -122.6764]
});
```

I am getting a:

```
throw new Error("Unknown type: " + geojson.type);

Error: Unknown type: undefined
```

What is the issue? It seems like this should not even be a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arcgis parser expects the x and y coordinates to be of type "number", not string as you have it in your example.

Just change your arcgis json x and y to floats, like this:

```
var primitive = ArcGIS.parse({
    x:-122.6764,
    y:45.5165,
    spatialReference: {
        wkid: 4326
    }
});
```